# Flutter firebase-messaging+firebase-analytics Exception thrown while unbinding

Tags: flutter

When I using Flutter package firebase-messaging + firebase-analytics and do all step from instruction, I receive following error:

```
W/ConnectionTracker(19182): Exception thrown while unbinding
W/ConnectionTracker(19182): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lt@ce461a
W/ConnectionTracker(19182):     at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1289)
W/ConnectionTracker(19182):     at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1511)
W/ConnectionTracker(19182):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:648)
W/ConnectionTracker(19182):     at ci.f(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714052@20.47.14 (040700-0):1)
W/ConnectionTracker(19182):     at ci.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714052@20.47.14 (040700-0):2)
W/ConnectionTracker(19182):     at lu.E(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714052@20.47.14 (040700-0):9)
W/ConnectionTracker(19182):     at le.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714052@20.47.14 (040700-0):3)
W/ConnectionTracker(19182):     at eg.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714052@20.47.14 (040700-0):3)
W/ConnectionTracker(19182):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
W/ConnectionTracker(19182):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/ConnectionTracker(19182):     at iz.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204714052@20.47.14 (040700-0):5)
```

app gradle.build

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'http://download.flutter.io'
        }
    }
}
```

app module build.gradle ( I tried different combinations)

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dependencies {
    /*implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'*/
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.5.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.5.0'
}
```

pubspec.yaml

```
  ...other packages
  firebase_core: ^0.5.3
  firebase_analytics: ^6.3.0
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
```

I found solution that there is nothing to do on developer side and we must to wait until February for some updates. May be somebody can find solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a warning, as indicated by W Prefix. if the functionality if working fine then there's nothing to worry about.